# Http status 401 spring cloud gateway token relay

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, okta, spring-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud gateway service as Oauth2 client and Token Relay, which is configured with Oauth2 resource server. This setup works fine using Okta as authorization server but changing to Google, results in an HTTP 401 when the gateway tries to request the secured service. Below my configurations:

Gateway aplication.yml

```
server:
  port: 80
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          okta:
            provider: okta
            client-id: ${OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: openid,profile,email
          google:
            provider: google
            client-id: ${GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: openid,profile,email
        provider:
          okta:
            issuer-uri: <my_okta_uri>
          google:
            issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: user
          uri: lb://USER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/user/**
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
            - RewritePath=/user(?<params>/?.*), $\{params}
        - id: category
          uri: lb://CATEGORY-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/category/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/category(?<params>/?.*), $\{params}
        - id: income
          uri: lb://INCOME-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/income/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/income(?<params>/?.*), $\{params}
        - id: expense
          uri: lb://EXPENSE-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/expense/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/expense(?<params>/?.*), $\{params}
        - id: budget
          uri: lb://BUDGET-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/budget/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/budget(?<params>/?.*), $\{params}
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org:
      springframework:
        cloud:
          gateway:
            filter: TRACE
```

Protected service application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enabled: false
  application:
    name: user-service
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: ${MONGO_URI}
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
#          issuer-uri: <my_okta_uri>
          issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    org.springframework.web.HttpLogging: DEBUG
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org.springframework.security.oauth2: DEBUG
    org.springframework.cloud.gateway: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Auth0.  It looked like the TokenRelay filter was not passing the JWT as the Bearer token.  It was providing a different access token from the OAuth2AuthorizedClient.  There may be a way to provide a different OAuth2AuthorizedClient or configure this differently, but I couldn't figure it out.

However, the exchange provided to the filter was already authenticated, so it had the JWT token I wanted to send to my backend services. I think this was because my backend service endpoints were configured as authenticated:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/service/**").authenticated()
                .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        http.oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
    }
```

So I wrote a custom OidcTokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory:

```
public class OidcTokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<Object> {

    public OidcTokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "OidcTokenRelay";
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Object config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal()
                .filter(principal -> principal instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken)
                .cast(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)
                .map(OAuth2AuthenticationToken::getPrincipal)
                .filter(principal -> principal instanceof OidcUser)
                .cast(OidcUser.class)
                .map(token -> withOidcIdToken(exchange, token.getIdToken()))
                .defaultIfEmpty(exchange).flatMap(chain::filter);
    }

    private ServerWebExchange withOidcIdToken(ServerWebExchange exchange, OidcIdToken accessToken) {
        return exchange.mutate().request(r -> r.headers(headers -> headers.setBearerAuth(accessToken.getTokenValue())))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Then I registered a bean for the FilterFactory like how the original TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory worked:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.cloud.gateway.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@ConditionalOnClass({ OAuth2AuthorizedClient.class, SecurityWebFilterChain.class, SecurityProperties.class })
@ConditionalOnEnabledFilter(OidcTokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory.class)
public class OidcTokenRelayConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OidcTokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory myTokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory() {
        return new OidcTokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory();
    }

}
```

Finally, I updated my Spring configuration file to use my custom filter.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: cluster-api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
          filters:
            - OidcTokenRelay=
            - StripPrefix=2
          predicates:
            - Path="/service/{serviceId}/**"
```

With these changes, I was able to route requests to my backend services without receiving a 401 response.